# Magento Block Extension - Ajax Controller Html Output Layout

Tags: html, ajax, magento, controller, output

Currently, i'm working on an AJAX-Controller for my finished Extension.

AjaxController.php - Controller
Lager.php -  Extension itself - has HTML outputs

the extension Lager.php runs only on the product view page, styled via catalog.xml in base/default/layouts and shows up under the pricebox.

So. The AjaxRequest, which is sent up by another extension which doesn't matters, works fine like the AjaxController too. But there's a problem. In AjaxController.php i've got a command to execute a function in Lager.php. It does, and with firebug i'm able to see, that he got the right response (the HTML output) too, but i think the layout is false. .. The new Html doesn't show up anywhere on the product view.

AjaxController.php (works fine but no HTML output, or no styling.. cause in html output in firebug theres no included css anymore):

```
<?php

require_once "Mage/Catalog/controllers/ProductController.php";

class Lager_Lager_AjaxController extends Mage_Catalog_ProductController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }

    public function refreshAction()
    {
        $selected = $this->getRequest()->getParam('selected');

        if($selected == 'true')
        {
            $productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('productid');
        if($productId)
        {
            $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlockSingleton('lager/lager')->runLager($productId); //does html output
        }
    }
    else
    {

    }
}
}

?>
```

The config.xml part of the ajax implementation:

```
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <lager>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
                <module>Lager_Lager</module>
                <frontName>lager</frontName>
            </args>
        </lager>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

the catalog.xml part of the extension implementation:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view" name="product.info" template="catalog/product/view.phtml">
            <!--
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>default</type><template>review/helper/summary.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>short</type><template>review/helper/summary_short.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addReviewSummaryTemplate"><type>...</type><template>...</template></action>

            BEGIN LAGER IMPLEMENTATION  -->

            <block type="lager/lager" name="lager" template="lager/lager.phtml" /> <!-- Lager Einbindung -->
            <lager_ajax_refresh>
                <block type="lager/lager" name="lager" output="toHtml" template="lager/lager.phtml" />
            </lager_ajax_refresh>

 <!--     END   -->

            <block type="catalog/product_view_media" name="product.info.media" as="media" template="catalog/product/view/media.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="alert.urls" as="alert_urls" translate="label">
                <label>Alert Urls</label>
            </block>

            <action method="setTierPriceTemplate"><template>catalog/product/view/tierprices.phtml</template></action>
```

So the Ajax Controller doesn't use the layout configuration of the extension which is implemented in catalog.xml ..

http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3601/h94loqef_png.htm

Comment: Checkout VF_EasyAjax https://github.com/hws47a/VF_EasyAjax

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But i don't look through EasyAjax. How does it work ? Can you explain please ? And what can i do for my project by learning from EasyAjax ? Is it the Layout-Handling there which i've to look about ?

The extension SCP (Simple Configurable Products) works with the ProductController and json too. How can i display my new HTML like there ?

Comment: It allows any controller to be used as AJAX, without needing to write special controller conditions, see the example: https://github.com/hws47a/VF_AjaxCart

Comment: Is there an option to get it running without the use of other extensions ?

Thank you very much

Comment: // EDIT:

Got it running. I forgot that AJAX only give responses in case of outputs like "echo" or HTML Tags. I handled this responses via Clientside Javascript where i sent up the Request and replaced the old HTML DIV Tag with the Response.

Thank you